# Order unversioned files in PhpStorm by folder

Tags: file, phpstorm

I wonder if there is any way in PhpStorm IDE to order the Unversioned Files (in the bottom window under "9: Changes" tab) by the folder in which they are, instead than by their file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the "Group by Directory" button (or CTRL + P) that groups the files into folders.

This is not exactly what I wanted though, because in this way I have to explore the folder tree.
Instead, I would like a list of files (as before), but ordered by folder name.